# Cases Page Layout Design Question

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, fields, ui

I've added a field to Cases that relate to an Opportunity. 'Insurance Carrier'

I'd like that field of the Opportunity to surface under a Tab in the page layout instead of in the details of the Case.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but if you have MasterDetail relationship between Case and Opp then you can add child object's detail in parent object from Related List option from page layout

Comment: Thanks for the thought but I don't think that would work if I understand this correctly. Opp can have multiple Cases in the Service Cloud, but I'm wanting a Case object to reference the Opp fields, so it can't be a MasterDetail relationship in that sense.